# Verify that a certain function satisfy an ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, leibniz-integral-rule

The question is:

**Show that the function**

$y={2\over\pi}\int_0^{\pi\over2}\cos(x\sin(\theta))d\theta$

**satisfy the ODE** $y''+{y'\over x}+y=0$.

I tried use the Leibniz rule for integration and end up with the following equation:

$y''+{y'\over x}+y={2\over \pi}\int_0^{\pi\over2}\left[\cos(x\sin(\theta))\cos^2(\theta)-{\sin(x\sin(\theta))\sin(\theta)\over x}\right]d\theta$

But I don't know what to do to proceed.

Comment: ...Indeed you will find all you need [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function) with index $n=0$.

Comment: Try to use instead $y = \frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}e^{i x\sin\theta}d\theta$

Comment: Yeah, I knew about Bessel function, but in the program this question appears befores the use of series to solve ODE, so I was trying to verify without using the fact that this was a Bessel function. But I appreciate the help anyway, thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$
\frac{d}{dθ}\Bigl[\sin(x\sin(θ))\cos(θ)\Bigr]
=x\cos(x\sin(θ))\cos^2(θ)-\sin(x\sin(θ))\sin(θ)
$$
and apply this and the fundamental theorem to your last integral.

Comment: Wow, It's funny how sometimes the answer is right in front of you and you can't see. Thank you.